# Regex Fail2ban Rule

Tags: regex, rules, fail2ban

I wanted to test fail2ban but I'm hitting a problem. My trys with regex does not really works.
The username e.g. userxy which occurs in the the first line of the log and in the second line the IP Address must be blocked by fail2ban.

/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf

```
[Filter1]
enabled   = true
filter    = test
port      = 12345
protocol  = tcp
logpath   = /var/etc/logs/auth.log
banaction = iptables-multiport
findtime  = 1800
bantime   = 3600
```

/var/etc/logs/auth.log

```
2018/09/21 20:45:13 ASDFDGFS c    (trail) password for 'userxy' invalid!
2018/09/21 20:45:13 ASDFDGFS c   (client) anonymous disconnected from 192.168.252.37
```

/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/test.conf

```
[Init]
maxlines = 2

[Definition]
failregex = ^.*userxy*\n.*anonymous disconnected from <HOST>.*$

ignoreregex =
```

Comment: Check this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/645644/writing-a-fail2ban-multiline-regex